# How did the terrorists hide the nuclear weapons inside the figures?

Tags: plot-explanation, true-lies

In *True Lies*, the terrorist group hides a nuclear warhead inside archeological figures. How did they do this without damaging or destroying it?

Did no one notice the modifications, or at least to the point of suspecting something?

[image]
[image]

Comment: haha, I thought about this too because she says, "they are priceless", but then how would they be priceless if they've been modified??

Comment: Indeed, since they were modified isn’t the same anymore, or this isn’t the original ones from the start....

Answer (score 9):

> How did they do this without damaging or destroying it?

#### They didn't

It's pretty clear that they *did* damage the artifacts to hide the weapons inside. They just made superficial covers to hide what was inside.

> Did no-one notice the modifications, at least to the point of suspecting something?

#### Who would notice?

The statues and weapons have been in the possession of Khaled & June for a month (I think a period of four weeks is mentioned). Then they were shipped, by sea, in crates.

June is a dealer in antiquities and was paid $2m to obtain the statues. They had plenty of time to make the modifications and return the statues to the *appearance* of normality.

Assuming the weapons were secreted in the statues before shipping, which seems likely, then there would only be a cursory inspection by a customs agent on loading.

June is a known dealer, importing goods and artifacts from all the Middle East (it's stated)...this would be just another shipment as far as the outside world is concerned.